# Messed up connection string in .Net 8.0 Firebird connector

Tags: .net, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I use .Net 8.0 for my app that should create database files on the fly if they don't exist.

I'm forwarding a Firebird Docker container to localhost port 3051 for debugging purposes, connection string is still the one one the container, and looks as follows :

```
datasource=localhost;database=\firebird\data\dbname.FDB;user id=SYSDBA;password=********;port number=3051;dialect=3;pooling=False;server type=0;character set=UTF8;connection lifetime=15;min pool size=0;max pool size=50;packet size=8192;wire crypt=Enabled
```

The problem occurs when I try to create a database in a sub-folder on the host, e.g. at `/firebird/data/subfolder/mydb.FDB` by calling:

```
FbConnection.CreateDatabase("datasource=localhost;database=\firebird\data\subfolder\mydb.FDB;...", 8192);
```

This returns the following error:

> Use of database at location /tmp/\firebird\data\subfolder\mydb.FDB is not allowed by server configuration

Where is this `/tmp/` coming from? (also, there seem to be some issues with forward and backward slashes, because in debug mode I use Windows, but the app will be deployed as a Linux-based Docker container).

On the Linux-based server, the error message looks as follows:

> Use of database at location /tmp/firebird/data/Open/1.FDB is not allowed by server configuration

Note that I made sure the sub-folder exists on the host and has the same privileges than the `/firebird/data` folder (the bonus here would be if the `FbConnection` could create sub-directories if required).

Comment: What is the setting in `firebird.conf` for setting `DatabaseAccess`?

Comment: After multiple testing - it appears that using sub-folder in `Restrict` mode works, provided the sub-folders already exist. Moreover, when using the `Path.Combine` on windows (in debug mode as in my case) to build the connection string on a linux-based container is a killer, as it will use "\" in paths (i.e. "\\firebird\\data\\subfolder\\mydb.FDB", which the firebird server takes as a filename and hence moves it to the "/tmp" folder.
It is still a bit of a surprise to see the server changing the connection string automatically though!

Comment: You don't seem to have edited the question. In any case, the "problem" is formally not Firebird's, Linux only supports forward slash as a path separator, and backslash is simply an allowed character in a filename. What you offer Firebird is either 1) a database alias, or otherwise 2) an absolute or 3) relative file path. Given this is a relative path, it is resolved against a server configuration (maybe even build) dependent file location, which in this case seems to be `/tmp`.

Comment: The behaviour on the Linux-based server seems to suggest, you offered it `firebird/data/Open/1.FDB` instead of `/firebird/data/Open/1.FDB` in that case.